# Заполнение FIFOBuffer

Tags: c++, poco

Как добавить в буфер элемент? Пробовал:

```
std::string str = "qwerty";
std::string str2 = "test";
//std::cout << str[0];
FIFOBuffer buf(str.c_str(),6);
buf.write(str2.c_str(), 4);
```

[Документация](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.html#12253)

Comment: Уточните в вопросе, что именно вы хотите сделать и что получаете в итоге. Короче говоря, создайте [mcve]. В текущем виде вопрос не полон и может быть закрыт путём голосования другими участниками.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по документации, срабатывает

```
BasicFIFOBuffer(
    const T * pBuffer,
    std::size_t size,
    bool notify = false
);
```

т.е. создается буфер из 6 символов, и уже заполненный. Дописать туда еще что-то без расширения крайне проблематично...

Проверьте, что возвращает вызов `isFull()`. Записывать можно, если `isWritable()` вернет `true`.

Увеличить размер буфера - `resize`.

Это все - просто при беглом взгляде на документацию... Так что теоретически у вас могут быть и еще какие-то ошибки, но пока посмотрите на эти.

Comment: `FIFOBuffer` это `typedef` для `BasicFIFOBuffer<char>`, так что с созданием всё нормально.

Comment: Охотно поверю. Замечание убираю.